# Give unique keys in a pandas df with rows that satisfy condition having common key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, key

I have a data frame like this:

```
d = {'id1':['3def','xyx1','roro','p344o','fjfje'],
     'id2':['hhyy','drdr','xyx1','xyx1','xyx1']
     ,'score':[100,90,100,90,70]
    }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1
        id1  id2    score
0   3def    hhyy    100
1   xyx1    drdr    90
2   roro    xyx1    100
3   p344o   xyx1    90
4   fjfje   xyx1    70
```

My end goal is to give a unique key to each row. The problem is that i would like the set of rows where the id1 equals the id2 & have score more than 80 to have a common key (in my case index 1,2,3). So i would like my desired result to be like this:

```
    id1     id2     score    uid
0   3def    hhyy    100      1
1   xyx1    drdr    90       2
2   roro    xyx1    100      2
3   p344o   xyx1    90       2
4   fjfje   xyx1    70       3
```

I have done something but doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
msk = (((df1['id1'].isin(df1['id2']).shift(-1)) (df1['id2'].isin(df1['id2']).shift(-1))) &\
           (df1['score'] > 80).shift(-1))

df1['uid'] = msk.cumsum()

print(df1)
     id1      id2   score   uid
0   3def    hhyy    100     1
1   xyx1    drdr    90      2
2   roro    xyx1    100     3
3   p344o   xyx1    90      3
4   fjfje   xyx1    70      3
```

Any help on how to solve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: In your dataframe, I see that there are multiple instances of id2.  Can there also be multiple instances of id1?

Comment: No, you can find only in id2

Comment: I don't see any rows in your example where `id1` equals `id2`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the logic on how uid increments.  It increments for each unique value in id2 or if score is less than 80?

Comment: @Mortz Sorry if i was not very clear. I meant where the id1 of one row equals the id2 of another row. Not for the same row

Comment: But roro, p344o, fjfje are all unique. So it seems it is based on id2?

Comment: @brb So if there are rows that share the ids( speciffically id1 of one row equals the id of another row) & score is more than 80, then i want those rows to have common key.

Comment: It would help if you give the expected output - what you want your final result to look like

Comment: @Mortz I have already. It's the second dataframe in order . i've provided it as my desired result.

Comment: I think I've find a solution, but when I try this line of your code: `msk = (((df1['id1'].isin(df1['id2']).shift(-1)) (df1['id2'].isin(df1['id2']).shift(-1))) &\
           (df1['score'] > 80).shift(-1))` it gives me an error: `'Series' object is not callable`. It works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm:

- create a uid per group of id1
- map those uids on the value of id2 and replace the uid if score matches the criterion
- eventually fix the non sequential uid by subtracting the extra difference

```
# step 1
df1['uid'] = df1.groupby('id1', sort=False).ngroup().add(1)

# step 2
alt_uid = df1['id2'].map(df1.set_index('id1')['uid']).convert_dtypes()

# step 3
df1['uid'] = df1['uid'].mask(df1['score'].gt(80) & alt_uid.notna(), alt_uid)

# final uid
df1['uid'] -= df1['uid'].diff().sub(1).fillna(0).clip(lower=0)
```

output:

```
     id1   id2  score  uid
0   3def  hhyy    100    1
1   xyx1  drdr     90    2
2   roro  xyx1    100    2
3  p344o  xyx1     90    2
4  fjfje  xyx1     70    3
```

output with intermediary steps:

```
     id1   id2  score  uid  uid_step1  uid_step2  uid_step3
0   3def  hhyy    100    1          1       <NA>          1
1   xyx1  drdr     90    2          2       <NA>          2
2   roro  xyx1    100    2          3          2          2
3  p344o  xyx1     90    2          4          2          2
4  fjfje  xyx1     70    3          5          2          5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier to create a custom function:

```
def func(data):
    idx, cur_id, cur_score, result = 0, None, None, []
    for x, y, z in data.values:
        if not ((cur_id == y) & (z > 80)):
            cur_id, cur_score = x, z
            idx += 1
        result.append(idx)
    return result

df["new"] = func(df)

print (df)

     id1   id2  score  new
0   3def  hhyy    100    1
1   xyx1  drdr     90    2
2   roro  xyx1    100    2
3  p344o  xyx1     90    2
4  fjfje  xyx1     70    3
```

Comment: minus 1, & is misused and they dont recomment values anymore